# How to configure BIOSLoader to boot with a static IP?

Tags: windows, networking, embedded, windows-ce, boot

Found this article on how to [boot BIOSLoader from USB.](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2009/07/12/platform-builder-setting-up-a-usb-key-to-run-biosloader.aspx)

However, I am failing to find information on how to set-up a static IP for the target device it is booting (so that there is Ethernet connectivity to upload OS image).

How do I configure BIOSLoader to launch an Ethernet bootloader, EBOOT.BIN with a specific static IP?

Any point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an entry named DbgIP to your boot.ini file.
You can find more detailed information here:
http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/SamuelPhung/tabid/72/entryid/204/Using-Static-IP-Addresses-for-Windows-Embedded-Compact.aspx

Comment: Is EBOOT.BIN compatible with most x86 boards and Ethernet controllers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739167/is-eboot-bin-compatible-with-most-x86-boards-and-ethernet-controllers